# How do I configure my Django REST framework view to recognize my "Authorization" header?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication, django-3.2, django-contrib

I'm using Django 3.2 with djangorestframework==3.12.2.  DRF doesn't seem to be recognizing/parsing the authorization header I'm sending with my requests.  I have this set up in my settings file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
         'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
         ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    )
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

}
```

and in the relevant view, I set up my perms and auth classes like so

```
class UserProfileView(RetrieveAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_class = JSONWebTokenAuthentication

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            token = get_authorization_header(request).decode('utf-8')
            if token is None or token == "null" or token.strip() == "":
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Authorization Header or Token is missing on Request Headers')
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY)
            username = decoded['username']
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
            response = {
                'success': 'true',
                'status code': status_code,
                'message': 'User profile fetched successfully',
                'data': {
                        'email': user.email
                    }
                }

        except Exception as e:
            status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            response = {
                'success': 'false',
                'status code': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                'message': 'User does not exists',
                'error': str(e)
                }
        return Response(response, status=status_code)
```

configurign this in my urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(r'profile/', views.UserProfileView.as_view()),
]
```

However when I restart my server and try and hit the endpoint

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --header "Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRhdmUiLCJleHAiOjE2MzM5ODMwMTUsImVtYWlsIjoiZGF2ZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSJ9.un6qNSdOQ-ExJxAQAIJIqwxyHeidx_2pXP8f1_mqLZY" "http://localhost:8000/profile/"
```

I get the error

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

How do I configure the endpoint to read the token submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add JWT before the token in your header

```
 "Authorization: JWT <your_token>"
```

refer this docs: https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/